# Forcefully make element go to another line in FlexBox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a page which I have to split into 2 pages. Initially, I had done it using ordinary table with 2 td tags. But later realised that formatting I want to do there is impossible using table. So I decided to use FlexBox instead. And it works so well, except of `flex-wrap: wrap;` tag. It only make 2nd row if zoom is very big.

[Usual zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ha10.png)

[Zoom 1.5x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqEqr.png)

[Well, the way I want to be 'sticked' is like this whatever zoom size is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFKWn.png)

I know that flexbox makes everything in one row when `display: flex` is declared. But how can I avoid it? And what is the proper way to adjust location of div elements in this case? For example when I declare

```
.chooseWord 
{
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 300px;
}
```

I want ONLY the word 'Choose' to go left for 300px. Instead whole leftSide goes left...

Here's my code:

```css
.flex-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.leftSide {
  padding-top: 30px;
  /* flex-basis: 50%; */
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 2px solid #05788D;
}

.rightSide {
 /* flex-basis: 50%; */
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 2px solid #05788D;
  border-left-style: none;
}

.SSRSSObjectCostTableTest {
  border: 3px solid #05788D;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.sideForSSRSSTables {
  border: 3px solid #05788D;
}

.partsTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.sideForPartsTable {
  border: 3px solid #05788D;
}

.chooseSRSS {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.chooseWord {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Main thing, that splits it into 2 pages -->

<div class="flex-container">

  <!-- This is our left side -->

  <div class="leftSide">

    <div class="chooseSRSS">
      <span class="chooseWord">Choose</span>
      <table class="SSRSSObjectCostTableTest" width="25%">
        <tr>
          <td class="sideForSSRSSTables">1st option</td>
          <td class="sideForSSRSSTables">2nd option</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div class="mainTable">

      <table>
        <!--styleClass="values-table"-->

        <tr>
          <td><b>Here's that table</b></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><b><input type="text" size="40" id="estCost_tsnb_title" value="Here's that table" width="25%"></b></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><b>Here's that table</b></td>
          <td>300</td>
          <td>$</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><b>Here's that table</b></td>
          <td>300</td>
          <td>$</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><b>Here's that table</b></td>
          <td>300</td>
          <td>$</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><b>Here's that table</b></td>
          <td>300</td>
          <td>$</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><b>Here's that table</b></td>
          <td>300</td>
          <td>$</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><b>Here's that table</b></td>
          <td>300</td>
          <td>$</td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
          <td><b>Here's that table</b></td>
          <td>300</td>
          <td>$</td>
        </tr>

        <!--styleClass="values-table"-->

        <tr>
          <td><b>Here's that table</b></td>
          <td>300</td>
          <td>$</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><b>Here's that table</b></td>
          <td>300</td>
          <td>$</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><b>Here's that table</b></td>
          <td>300</td>
          <td>$</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><b>Here's that table</b></td>
          <td>300</td>
          <td>$</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><b>Here's that table</b></td>
          <td>300</td>
          <td>$</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><b>Here's that table</b></td>
          <td>300</td>
          <td>$</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><b>Here's that table</b></td>
          <td>300</td>
          <td>$</td>
        </tr>

      </table>

    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- This is our right side -->

  <div class="rightSide">

    <div class="outerTable">

      <span class="partsText">Parts</span>
      <button type="button" class="addButton">+Add button</button>

      <!--<table class="outerPartTable">-->

      <div class="partsClass">

        <table class="partsTable">
          <td class="sideForPartsTable" width="5%">Expand button</td>
          <td class="sideForPartsTable">Title + sum1 + sum2</td>
          <td class="sideForPartsTable" width="5%">edit</td>
          <td class="sideForPartsTable" width="5%">remove</td>
        </table>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <!--</table>-->
</div>
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you are wanting to achieve. I will post my answer once I'm 100% sure of it. I've looked at it briefly and you must understand that `flex-wrap: wrap;` only works on the container, not the child elements of that container.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to achieve 1 page which equally split into 2 pages. On the left side, there's one block which has a word "Choose" and a sub-table(1st, 2nd option) and other big subtable UNDER this block. I want the block to be vertical, since that I've used flex here.  On the right side there're "Parts"  and "+Add button" also vertical, with a space between. And UNDER that other sub-table, called parts inside an outer table which stores all that parts(but horizontally)

Comment: Well then you wouldn't want the child element of `flex-container` to fall onto multiple lines. So `flex-wrap: wrap;` is not needed. Whilst I write this up, have a look at this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at this and let me know if anything else is needed.

```css
.flex-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}

.leftSide {
  padding-top: 30px;
  border: 2px solid #05788D;
  width: 50%;
}

.rightSide {
  border: 2px solid #05788D;
  border-left-style: none;
  width: 50%;
}

.partsTable, .leftSize table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.sideForPartsTable {
  border: 3px solid #05788D;
}
```

```html
<!-- Main thing, that splits it into 2 pages -->

<div class="flex-container">

  <!-- This is our left side -->
  <div class="leftSide">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Some text</td>
          <td>Some value</td>
          <td>Currency</td>
          <td>1st option</td>
          <td>2nd option</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><b>Here's that table</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><b>Here's that table</b></td>
          <td>300</td>
          <td>$</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><b>Here's that table</b></td>
          <td>300</td>
          <td>$</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><b>Here's that table</b></td>
          <td>300</td>
          <td>$</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><b>Here's that table</b></td>
          <td>300</td>
          <td>$</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><b>Here's that table</b></td>
          <td>300</td>
          <td>$</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <!-- This is our right side -->
  <div class="rightSide">



    <!--<table class="outerPartTable">-->

    <div class="partsClass">

      <table class="partsTable">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td> <span class="partsText">Parts</span></td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="addButton">+Add button</button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="sideForPartsTable">Expand button</td>
            <td class="sideForPartsTable">Title + sum1 + sum2</td>
            <td class="sideForPartsTable">edit</td>
            <td class="sideForPartsTable">remove</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Some value
            </td>
            <td>
              Some value
            </td>
            <td>
              Some value
            </td>
            <td>
              Some value
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>

<!--</table>-->
</div>
```

Comment: I'll rewrite the snippet as I think the HTML structure could be a lot better. It would be a lot easier to just have a flex container with two columns. Inside those two columns, contain a table for viewing data, and CRUD operations.

Comment: Well, "Choose and sub-table" are shrinked and crosses midlle of alleged table :c This is exactly what I got when was doing it with ordinary table

Comment: And the page isn't divided into 2 equal pieces :c

Comment: @RobertBaratheon If you haven't already, please take a look at the amended snippet and tick it if it's correct.